# More suitable word for 'reactionary'

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm looking for a word to describe a group of people who reacts whenever something happens. They are sure to react and are so nearsighted that their reactions are predictable. I was going to use the word 'reactionary' but realized that term has a specific political meaning. Is there a better word I can use for this purpose?

Example:
A conversation where "the industry is completely stupidly reactionary" comes up when they are talking about the stock market and how it reacts predictably to the news.

Comment: @grouchdoug [Here's the help](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). When you looked up *react,* since that's what the industry is doing, were there any adjectives suggested?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Reactive. But seems to me that it doesn't carry as much of a negative connotation as I want. Can't quite explain, but (to me) reactionary sounds a bit more negative and reactive is a bit less powerful/condemning -- if both were okay, that is.

Comment: @grouchdoug Thanks. All of these clarifications need to go into the question. No-one wants to trawl through the comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like "Pavlovian response" or "knee-jerk reaction".

The bigger problem is that your use of "react" and "stupidly" is 100% subjective. Many people react to reaction-worthy things: something falls from the roof, a gust of wind etc. The mere fact that people react to something doesn't mean anything. If your claim is that their reaction is wrong, you need to justify your claim.

Comment: I see. I shouldn't rely on this word or any particular word choice to encapsulate the point I'm trying to make. Rather, I should just elaborate on it (and I do -- was going to use this line as an introduction to an argument) and probably do away with the term/label altogether, is what you are trying to say. @MrSparkly